# Merging branches in Git

Tags: git, github, merge

I have 2 main branches in my git repository.

- `master`
- From master I created one more branch `stable`.

I created a child branch from stable, say `child1`. I made the changes in `child1` and pushed it to remote git repository. Since, we have a code review process that we follow. Meanwhile, the code in `child1` was under review, I created another branch `child2` from stable for another issue.

Now, I have some changes locally on top of the `child1`. What I want to do is to merge the changes from `child1` to the `stable` without affecting the changes in `child2` which is still under development.

PS: **Consider the stable branch is empty for now. I am merging to stable for the first time**

Answer (score 3):

Just merge `child1` into `stable`. `child2` will not be affected by this.

```
git checkout stable
git merge child1
```

What you have to do is update your 'child2' with the changes of `stable`.

1) You can do this by either **merge** `stable` into `child2`

```
 git checkout child2
 git merge stable
```

2) or you **rebase** `child2` onto the new `stable`

```
git checkout child2
git rebase stable
```

While **merge** makes the history graph all "diamondy", **rebase** will keep it! linear

Comment: Thanks. Does merging the changes from child1 to stable automatically updates the stable in remote location? Or do I need to push the stable again?

Comment: You have to push the changes again.
Allways remember only `push; pull; fetch` are network operations. Everything else is local

Comment: ok.. Thanks for the help. I will try it out. If you can direct me to some good link to understand this procedure. Please do.

Comment: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2 and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1ffBJ4sVUb4 helped me. Especially the Video!

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but are you aware that you don't HAVE TO merge to `stable`? You can push your local branch to remote, without merging it first. ( `git push origin child1` ) It will create a `child1` branch on remote for you. That probably saves you a lot of trouble in the future with keeping your local master and `origin` in sync. (Been there, done that.) If you need more info, just say the word.

Comment: Ofcourse he can do that, but as I have understood the Question is, that he is done with `child1` and wants to add the changes to the stable branch after fixing some flaws found in the code-review.
Pushing `child1` doesn't really help in this situation.